# Matlab GUI ODE solver 'Value' must be a double scalar

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make an 2nd order ODE solver but it's not working (Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.model.AbstractNumericComponent/set.Value (line 111)
'Value' must be a double scalar.) when I run it on the normal matlab (not the app designer), I get the right answer.

```
    m1 = app.m.Value;
    c1 = app.c.Value;
    k1 = app.k.Value;
    
    syms y(x)
Dy = diff(y);

ode = m1*diff(y,x,2) == app.u.Value - c1*Dy - k1*y;
cond1 = y(0) == 1;
cond2 = Dy(0) == 0;
conds = [cond1 cond2];
ySol(x) = dsolve(ode,conds);
ySol = simplify(ySol);
app.EditField.Value = ySol;
```